# Некорректный вывод матрицы в python

Tags: python, матрицы

Имеется код:

```
list = []
a, b = 0, 0
len_list = 5
while a < len_list:
    list.append([])
    while b < len_list:
        list[a].append([1])
        b += 1
    a += 1
for y in range(len(list)):
    for x in range(len(list[y])):
        print(list[y][x][0], end = " ")
    print()
```

По идее он должен выводит квадрат пять на пять из единиц.

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

Вместо этого он выводит лишь одну строчку из пяти единиц и еще четыре пустые строчки.

```
1 1 1 1 1
.
.
.
.
```

В чём моя ошибка? Она явно где-то в части кода создающей матрицу.

Comment: Не обнуляете `b` при генерации матрицы. Непонятно зачем вообще там `while` вместо `for .. xrange`

Comment: `b = 0` в начале каждой внешней итерации. и привыкайте сразу к хорошему стилю `lst = [[1] * len_list for _ in range(len_list)]`

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в увеличении переменной `b`, после первого прохода второго цикла `while` переменная `b` равна `5`, а значит последующие циклы заполнения матрицы не выполнятся. Необходима обнулять переменную `b` перед заполнением матрицы.